# I'm getting empty objects in my response likely do to unresolved promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, promise

Although I have a `.then()` after the promises it's returning before it's resolved. Please help me understand why. Thank you!

This file does the following:

- gets the data for each UPC
- stores the data in a database
- calls a function that modifies the data
- returns the modified data

```
const upcHelperMethods = require('./upc-helper-methods');
const UpcsService = require('./upc-service');

const AddByUpcService = {
    addProducts(upcsArray, db, next) {

    return Promise.all(upcsArray.reduce((acc, el) => {
            acc = acc.concat(apiGeniusApiService.getItemData(el, next))
            return acc
        }, []))
            .then(response => {
                return response.map(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    return UpcsService.insertUpc(db, data)
                        .then((results) => {
                            return upcHelperMethods.extractData(data)
                        })
                        .catch(next)
                })
            })
            .catch(next)
    }
}

module.exports = AddByUpcService
```

The following code communicates with the above file:

```
upcsRouter
    .route('/hard-data')
    .post(jsonParser, (req, res, next) => {

        AddByUpcService.addProducts(req.body.data, req.app.get('db'), next)
            .then(async (results) => {
                return res.status(201).json(results)
            }).catch((err) => {
                return res.status(400).end();
            })
    })
```

How can I wait for `results` to resolve before sending the response?
Thank you!

I get this when logging `results` to the console:

```
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
```

Comment: Instead of `reduce`+`concat`, use `flatMap`

Comment: What is `apiGeniusApiService.getItemData`? Does it return an array of promises (inferred from your usage)? Why are you passing `next` as an argument?

Comment: `response.map(…)` creates an array of promises. You will need another `Promise.all` to handle that.

Comment: Are you trying to use `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 1):

Use ***async/await*** so that the code waits until a response is received before moving onto the next line.

```js
const upcHelperMethods = require('./upc-helper-methods');
const UpcsService = require('./upc-service');

const AddByUpcService = {
  async addProducts(upcsArray, db, next) {

    try {
      const response = await Promise.all(upcsArray.reduce((acc, el) => {
        acc = acc.concat(apiGeniusApiService.getItemData(el, next))
        return acc
      }, []));

      return response.map(data => {
        console.log(data)
        const results = await UpcsService.insertUpc(db, data);
        return upcHelperMethods.extractData(data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next;
    }


  }
}

module.exports = AddByUpcService
```

```js
upcsRouter
  .route('/hard-data')
  .post(jsonParser, async(req, res, next) => {

    try {
      await AddByUpcService.addProducts(req.body.data, req.app.get('db'), next);
      return res.status(201).json(results);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).end();
    }
  })
```